# No wireless / wired on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, wired

Recently, I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 along with Windows 7 (after which I upgraded to Windows 8), but I have never been able to get any network connection on ubuntu, wireless nor wired. Works fine on Windows. I am on a HP ProBook 4510s.

My ethernet controller:

> Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller

My wireless controller:

> Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY

Comment: the output of `ifconfig` and the contents of /etc/networks/ may be helpful in working out the answer

Comment: For the wireless see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

(should be a comment, rep to low)
can you go through [this *Diagnose Network Problems yourself* step-by-step guide](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/diagnose-and-fix-network-problems-yourself) and if it doesn't solve your problem post your results here, that should give a better description of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved it in the meantime by plugging-in an ethernet cable and downloading wireless drivers. :)